# python virtualenv different behavior from activate and bin/python

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I created virtualenv for few months. And I encountered a problem.

When I activate virtual environment I have access to lib like django :

```
source virtualenv/jsms/bin/activate
(jsms)local% python
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> exit()
(jsms)local% deactivate
```

But when I use python from the **bin** folder I can't access to django :

```
local% virtualenv/jsms/bin/python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
```

More strange, when I use **python3.4** from the **bin** folder, I am using **python 2.7** :

```
local% virtualenv/jsms/bin/python3.4
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Do you know a way to access lib directly from python in the **bin** folder ?

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to? The reason you need to `activate` the virtual environment is because it's not just as simple as pointing to the correct interpreter. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to run django dev server from another python script. I tried to use **os.popen('~/virtualenv/jsms/bin/python ~/project/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000')** but it doesn't work. I can't use **os.popen('~/virtualenv/jsms/bin/activate')** 
then **os.popen('~/project/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000')**

Comment: Why can't the other script run in the same environment?

Comment: Because based python is manage by sysadmin in my company, developers use their virtualenv.

Answer (score 2):

activate is just a bash script, so you can always take a look at the activate file and see what it is doing, but I think what you’re looking for is the env variable `PYTHONHOME`.  I would try:

```
export OLD_PYTHON_HOME="$PYTHONHOME"
unset PYTHONHOME
virtualenv/jsms/bin/python3.4 --version
```

For windows, you would use the following code from the activate.bat template:

```
if defined PYTHONHOME (
    set _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME=%PYTHONHOME%
    set PYTHONHOME=
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need a solution that works with Mac OS and Windows.

Comment: I saw zero in your original post about windows, and command line for windows and command line for Mac OS are completely different unless you are using Windows 10’s built-in ubuntu.